# How to map name of property by using IConfigurationSectio.Get in .netCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having some troubles to map a name which is diferent in my config file, from a class I want to build.

My config file:

```
"148/FOEConfiguration":{  
    "EndPointUrl1":"http://10.116.105.25:8088/RPC2",
    "EndPointUrl2":"http://10.116.105.25:8088/RPC2",
    "FoeVersion":"6",
    "CryptoId":"6",
    "CryptoKey":"test",
    "NumberOfRetries":3,
    "OrderVersion":"2",
    "FOE.PODName":"FOE0001",
    "FOE.TimeoutInMs":123,
    "FOE.IsReadySuccCacheTtl":0,
    "FOE.IsReadyStoreFailCacheTtl":0,
    "FOE.IsReadyOrderFailCacheTtl":0
   }
```

And i'm doing

```
var section = _config.GetSection($"{restaurantNumber}/FOEConfiguration");
var restaurant = section.Get<RestaurantConfiguration>();
```

However in RestaurantConfiguration the property name is

```
public int TimeoutInMs { get; set; }
```

And in Config file is "FOE.TimeoutInMs"

How do I Map the property to the name in the config file?

Comment: Those are config files, why don't you make them equal? I don't see any kind of problem here. You either rename the properties (with `[JsonProperty]`) or fix the JSON.

Comment: IS there any reason why you can not change property names in config file?

Comment: The config file is generated by a third part, I don't have control over it. And also, a c# property cannot have "." in the name.
There are workarounds, but I want to know if there is a way to map and make it easier.
I tried using [JsonProperty] and it did not work

Answer (score 1):

The mapping of config values to properties is basic projection. There's no ability to customize the mapping per se. However, you can create a custom registration for your strongly-typed config:

```
services.Configure<RestaurantConfiguration>(c => {
    var config = Configuration.GetSection($"{restaurantNumber}/FOEConfiguration");
    c.TimeoutInMs = config.GetValue<int>("FOE.TimeoutInMs");
    // etc.
});
```

Comment: That's how i'm working around, I just wanted to know if there was a best way to do that.
Thanks Chris!